# Some Confusion / Query Related to MVC2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-2

I have just started using MVC 2 , I have got a couple of queries , may be you guys can help me to clear my confusion.

Why mvc doesnt allows to inherit multiple models on a view page. 
For instance if i inherited account model in my view , why i cant excess the associated entity properties with the account model in that view, We are only allowed to use the properties of that model like `<%: Model.FirstName :%>` Where First name is the property of account model. Why we cannot use `<%:Model.account.aspnet_users.vehicle.make %>` Where `aspnet_users` is associated with account through a foreign key vice versa. MVC 2 only allows `<%:Model.account.aspnet_users.vehicle %>` Therfore I cant use the associated property of vehicle which in this case is `vehicle.make`.  I was thinking of doing something like `<%: Html.TextboxFor(model => model.account.aspnet_users.vehicle.make %>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC doesn't restrict navigation to related properties. If you cannot access the property it means either:

- The relation is not loaded (it is null) and lazy loading is turned off / context is disposed
- The relation is actually a collection an you must use Linq to navigate in the collection

Comment: its a collection, y we cant use collection without using foreach

Comment: is it becuase I have one to multiple relation between the two models??

Comment: Yes if you have one to many relation your model will contain collection of related models